# Sepration of words and count in columns and seperate then in two words

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data set:

| Words | Count |
| --- | --- |
| Hello,World |  |
| World,%,Hello,Germany |  |
| Germany,100,ML,Germnay |  |

#### My Goal:

I would that the Code does:

- Separate the Words: (`"Hello,World"`) ---> (`"Hello","World"`)
- Lists all separated Words in new columns behind each other
- Count the frequency of Words and put the results in "Count" e.g. it finds two times the world "Hello" in column "Words"

| Words | Counts |
| --- | --- |
| Hello | 2 |
| World | 2 |
| % | 1 |
| 100 | 1 |
| ML | 1 |
| Germany | 3 |

#### What I did:

The type of "CL1" is "object"

```
import pandas as pd
import re

separators = ","

def get_word_len(words: str) -> int:
   return len(re.split(separators, words))

df["Count"] = df.Words.apply(get_word_len)

print(df)
```

But it counts the number of words in every cell and NOT the frequency and count of repetition in columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you cant use the string module in pandas :

```
df['Words'].str.split(',').explode().value_counts()
```

output:

```
Hello      2
World      2
Germany    1
%          1
ML         1
100        1
Name: Words, dtype: int64
```

to make it into a dataframe:

```
pd.DataFrame(df['Words'].str.split(',').explode().value_counts()).reset_index().rename({'index':"Words","Words":"Count"},axis=1)
```

output:

```
    Words   Count
0   Hello   2
1   World   2
2   Germany 1
3   %       1
4   ML      1
5   100     1
```

Answer (score 3):

One can use the above methods, and they are efficient.

Adding another way using `str.dummies` with `df.sum`

```
df['Words'].str.get_dummies(",").sum()

%          1
100        1
Germany    1
Hello      2
ML         1
World      2
dtype: int64
```

---

```
df['Words'].str.get_dummies(",").sum().rename_axis("Words").reset_index(name='Counts')

     Words  Counts
0        %       1
1      100       1
2  Germany       1
3    Hello       2
4       ML       1
5    World       2
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) for this:

```
>>> df
            Words
0     Hello,World
1   World,%,Hello
2  Germany,100,ML

>>> pd.Series(Counter(','.join(df.Words).split(',')), 
              name='count').rename_axis(df.columns[0]).reset_index()

     Words  count
0    Hello      2
1    World      2
2        %      1
3  Germany      1
4      100      1
5       ML      1
```

Timing:

```
>>> %timeit pd.DataFrame(df['Words'].str.split(',').explode().value_counts()).reset_index().rename({'index':"Words","Words":"Count"},axis=1)
1.53 ms ± 30.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

>>> %timeit pd.Series(Counter(','.join(df.Words).split(',')), name='count').rename_axis(df.columns[0]).reset_index()
873 µs ± 15 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
from collection import Counter

data = ",".join(df["Words"].tolist())

counter = Counter(data.split(","))

new_df = pd.DataFrame(dict(counter))
```